# Slider flashing on screen and loading weird

Tags: jquery, css

I am building this site and it has been tricky for me. The way it is designed with the nav, the logo/search bar area being transparent, and the slider behind that, has made it tough. When you load the page, you'll notice that the buttons and text on top of the slider page don't load at first. After a second they show up and the first slide image flashes back onto the screen. And if you scroll to the very bottom of the page, you can see the buttons and text load down there, then move up to the intended position. I always seem to have issues with the first slide flashing on the screen. Any ideas what is going on?

http://new.townofbargersville.org/

Note: I am using Chrome. In Safari the buttons and text don't even show up until the second slide transitions in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start call flexslider, the code moves the `ul.slides` to be the last element of the container (`div#banner`). This is why you see it after a few seconds.
If you didn't call it - you would never see the content of `div#banner-contact`, since it's positioned as absolute, and there is another layer above it (the `ul.slides`). The container `div#banner` has height of `634px` and `overflow: hidden` so anything below that will be hidden.

In order for this to work you should just change the order of your elements. Move `<ul class="slides">` under `<div id="banner-content">`

Comment: Thank you! You know, I kind of wondered if it would be something real simple, and it was. I just decided to post my problem on here and take a break before I lost my mind :)